# Xamarin Form - Can't get return value data from Service class method into MainPage method for filtering

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin, I have an app in Xamarin-Form that it's fetching data from web api and getting user input from Entry control.

The web api service class is working fine and reaches the deserialization in the **getCourses** method as seen below in **Code Snippet 1**.

The Entry control as well is working fine until it retrieves the user input on the MainPage class, **OnOkGetCourseButton** method as seen below **Code Snippet 2**.

What I want to achieve is, inside **MainPage.xaml.cs**, I create a method that takes the user input data and check agaisnt the deseriaized json data (the **Id** specially),

if it **finds the Id** in deserialized List of data, then it can send the found data to another ViewPage and display them.

if It cannot find the data, it shows a dialog box.

*So far, I tried to call **Task<ObservableCollection> getCourses()** method from the **MainPage** class, inside **CheckCourseComplete** as seen below but it giving me no value/nothing, some kind of null value.*

I don't want to filter the user input against web api json response inside **getCourses()**,
I want to do that in a separate method to follow **S**-OLID (*Single Responsibility Principle*).
If it's not possible in a separate method, then I just need to get it worked.

***Please what is the best way to achieve it?***

**Code Snippet 1**

```
       public class CourseService : ICourseService
       {
           
           string Base_Url = "https://www.test.com/api/TheCourse";
           
           public async Task<ObservableCollection<Course>> getCourses()
           {
               try
               {
                   string url = Base_Url;
   
                   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                   HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
   
                   if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                   {
                       var result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                       var deserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Course>>(result);
   
                       // I don't want to do that here, as it will violate SRP (SOLID)
   
                       return deserializedClass;
                   }
   
                   return null;
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   throw;
               }
           }
   
       }
```

**Code Snippet 2**

```
namespace CourseMobile
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private string _getEntryText;

        private readonly CourseViewModel orderViewModel;
        public Course FetchCourse { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckCourseComplete();
            BindingContext = new CourseViewModel();
        }

        public string GetEntryText 
        {
            get => _getEntryText;
            set => _getEntryText = value;
        }

        public async void OnOkGetCourseButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inputtedCourseNumber = this.GetEntryText;

            if(inputtedCourseNumber == string.Empty)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("", "Please enter your Course number", "OK 3");
            }
            else
            {
                CheckCourseComplete();

                this.GetEntryText = inputtedCourseNumber;

                await DisplayAlert("New Text", inputtedCourseNumber, "OK 2");
            }
        }

        void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newText = e.NewTextValue;
            this.GetEntryText = newText;
        }

        public async void CheckCourseComplete()
        {
            CourseService myCourse = new CourseService();

            await myCourse.getCourses();            // It doesn't return the json data (web api data)
            
            
            // I need to check user input + (web api data) here

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `getCourses` is async, so it needs to be called with await.  You need to read up on async/await.  Also you are doing a LOT of unnecessary work to deal with Entry.  You can just refer to "MyEntryName.Text", there is no need to use event handlers and properties to get the value.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Regarding **Async** I fixed that it was my mistake when typing into Stackoverflow. Thanks for the **Entry TEXT property**, will take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCourses` is async, so you need to use await when calling it

```
    public async void CheckCourseComplete()
    {
        CourseService myCourse = new CourseService();

        var data = await myCourse.getCourses();

        // now filter data
    }
```

Comment: I'm still stuck on The Entry. What if I have two entry on the same page, I would I handle it to get text from both Entry

Comment: assign each one of them a name using `x:Name` in the XAML, then refer to them by name in the code-behind

Comment: Thank you so much Jason. Please last thing, How do I add Loading image while Web Api is fetching data?

Comment: use ActivityIndicator

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much